# Fixing a 1920 row house - hardfloor cupping/buckle/warpping

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood

[image: hardwood bamboo engineered click]

So today my wife noticed the new floor (3 weeks installed) has a funny feel in one spot.  I noticed a few wood panels look warped and cupped   particularly in one area.  What causes that and how to correct it. ?

Comment: Did you give the new flooring at least 2 weeks soak time in your house before installing?  If not, you may see this problem repeat itself at other locations.

Comment: Over 2 weeks but they still in the boxes for the most part.   Is there anything I can do to correct it? Aside from sanding which seems drastic.  I mean it seemed to happen over the coarse of a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moisture can often cause that, if a spill isn't cleaned up promptly or you mop with excessive water, for example.

Likewise, if this is over a wet basement this can happen, but I would bet the issue is from the top half of the floor (in the room).

Less likely is that there is not enough of an expansion gap between the sides of the floor and the wall, and temperature changes in the room are forcing the boards into each other (though the damage in this case is quite possibly more extensive).

Comment: So it is in my bedroom and I also think our toddler spilled a cup of water there so that ties it together.  Will it dry out and fix itself? Or is it ruined permanently- just like that?

Comment: It's possible over time (weeks/months) that the wood can dry out and return close to normal, but I believe you'll usually be stuck sanding the floors for any immediate result. You could always throw down a rug to hide it, but it would be a shame -- that floor looks beautiful.

Comment: It may also be caused by whatever you covered over. If the floor beneath it was old wood that was already not that dry, the new wood will absorb water from beneath. With time it may stabilize. There are also a few "remedies" you could try. http://homeguides.sfgate.com/fix-bowed-floors-63409.html

Comment: Thanks Trevor for the remedy resource - I did put down a subfloor vapor barrier so it seems to definitely come from up top.  My wife recalls my toddler son spilling water there at one point - but I guess it was cleared up quickly.   Concerned because I am doing his room next with the same flooring.